# Is it allowed to solve this inequality $x|x-1|>-3$ by dividing each member with $x$?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Is it allowed to solve this inequality  $x|x-1|>-3$ by dividing each member with $x$? What if $x$ is negative?

My textbook provides the following solution:

> Divide both sides by $x: $ $\frac { x | x - 1 | } { x } > \frac { - 3
>  } { x } ; \quad x \neq 0$
>
> Simplify: $| x - 1 | > - \frac { 3 } { x } ; \quad x \neq 0$

Edit: provided textbook's solution

Comment: If negative, reverse the inequality.

Comment: You must not divide by $x$ if $x$ is $0$ (and in fact $x=0$ is a solution of $x|x-1|>-3$!!). And you must reverse the inequality if you divide by negative $x$. -- It seems more adequate to solve the cases $x^2-x>-3\land x\ge 1$ and $x-x^2>-3\land x<1$

Comment: Before you divide by $x$ make sure to check the case where $x=0$, as it is possible that it could also make the inequality true...

Answer (score 3):

For $x\geq0$ this inequality is always true.

Assume that $x<0$, so $x=-y$ for some positive $y$ and we get $$y|\;\underbrace{y+1}_{>0}\;|<3\implies y(y+1)<3 ...$$

Answer (score 3):

[image]
${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I wish the students would learn to do this themselves. It makes concepts such as growth, derivative, concrete if your own hands have drawn a picture.

Comment: In my primary school days in Singapore (and also now) we always drew models to solve problems that were ultimately algebraic in nature. As we progressed, into secondary school and into universities, we went into more complicated diagrams like function graphs, Argand planes, Venn systems and so on. We follow the thinking of pictures, in essence. As for myself, having also drawn MLPFIM stuff for some six years now, mathematical pictures are one of my loves.

Answer (score 0):

Because, the inequality holds for $x \ge 0$, let's consider the case $x<0$. 
In this case, $|x-1|=-x+1$ and we have $-x^2+x+3>0$. The roots of the quadratic are $x_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2},x_2=\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ so the inequality also holds when $\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2} < x <0$